# Checking login status and changing navbar text based on it (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a login and registration form on React. 
It looks like:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            isLoading: false
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }


    handleClick(){

        var self = this;

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/signin', 
        {
            username:this.state.username, 
            password:this.state.password
        })
            .then(function (response) {

            console.log(response);
            if(response.data.status === "Successful"){
                console.log("Login successfull");
            }

            else{
                console.log("There is no user with the given username and password");
                //alert("Username does not exist");
            }
            }
        )
        .catch(function (error) {

        console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
              <div>
               <TextField
                 hintText="Enter your Username"
                 floatingLabelText="Username"
                 onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({username:newValue})}
                 />
               <br/>
                 <TextField
                   type="password"
                   hintText="Enter your Password"
                   floatingLabelText="Password"
                   onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({password:newValue})}
                   />
                 <br/>
                 <RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true} style={style} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
             </div>
             </MuiThemeProvider>
          </div>
    );
}
}   

export default LoginForm;
```

Whenever I signin correctly, it gives me a successful response.

What I want to ask it, how can I pass in the login status to another component and render based on it? For example, I want to change the text `Sign in` to `Sign out` when the user is logged on. My navbar comp looks like:

```
const Link = props => (
  <NavLink className="nav-link" {...props}>
    <div className="link-container">
      <div>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </NavLink>
);

const Navbar = () => (
  <div className="navbar">
    <div className="logo-container">
    </div>

    <div className="left-link-container">
      <Link to="/i/#">ABOUT</Link>
      <Link to="/i/#">MENU 2</Link>
      <Link to="/i/#">MENU 3</Link>
    </div>

    <div className="right-link-container">
      <Link to="/signin">Sign In</Link>
      <Link to="/signup">Register</Link>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Navbar;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you considered using Redux in your project? I am not sure whether solving this case by case would be a good solution instead you can try out a state manager like Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using any common shareable state among this components. It means that you have some state like:

```
const state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
}
```

Then you should pass this `isAuthenticated` to all the components you need. Also, you need to add some functions to change the status.

Possible ways to implement such a thing:

- a common parent component with the state written above that passes `isAuthenticated` to children.
- using [redux](https://redux.js.org/) which is a perfect way to have a shareable state.
- using [React.Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to provide the state through the context.

Comment: If I set the default as false, wouldn't it always re-render it to false whenever I load components? Also, are there any good examples that shows shared states:?

Comment: @Dawn17 It will not be re-rendered if it is the highest order component which is always mounted. Inside this component, you will do changes. But the best way to handle it is by using redux. [Here](https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/) is a good example of using redux for authentication.